# What happens to my comment if the parent question/answer is deleted?

Tags: support, comments

Let's say that I leave a comment on a question,  responding to an answer that was left.

Can the person who left the answer delete his answer and my comment?  I didn't think that it was possible, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the parent post is deleted, the comment is as well.

Comment: So if there was multiple comment to an answer, and that answer was deleted, all comment will be deleted?

Comment: @Mitch yes. But with the difference that if/when the answer is undeleted, the comments will be back as well.

Comment: thanks, that's good to know.  Appreciate it