# How can I view a comment for a deleted answer?

Tags: support

I had posted a comment to an answer to this [question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8079/25656). From my inbox, I can see that there was a response but now that answer and all associated comments including the response to my comment aren't visible. And the bit in my inbox is truncated:

[image: inbox message]

I understand that certain measures are being used to control certain activities and that may explain the vanishing of the answer and its comments. *If it's not a problem and if it increases my understanding of how the site works,* I'd like to know the gist of the comment which is only partly visible in my inbox.

(I've seen [this QnA](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3439/25656) dealing with deleted answers and associated comments.)

Comment: Unfortunately, only questioners can be forced to register. There currently exists no such feature for answerers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get 10k rep you can see delete answers, but the comment says:

> @vasa1 Unfortunately, only questioners can be forced to register. There currently exists no such feature for answerers. –  jokerdino♦ 9 hours ago

Comment: At 10k rep, can we also expand the comments on deleted posts? Or, do the comments get locked and we can only view the 5 that is by default available to view?

Comment: @Aditya you can view all non-deleted comments on everthing.